# List files from directories and sub directories in java including only partial file paths

Tags: java

I need to get the paths of files and their parent directories in java from a given directory but not including it.

So for example, If my method was given the path: `/home/user/test` as a path it would return the paths of all files in that directory and under it.

So if `/home/user/test` had the sub folders: `/subdir1` and `/subdir2` each containing `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` then the result of the method would be 2 strings containing `/subdir1/file1.txt` and `/subdir2/file2.txt`

And if `subdir1` had a directory inside it called `subsubdir` and inside that `file3.txt`, then the string created for that file would be `/subdir1/subsubdir/file3.txt`, and if there are further sub directories that would continue.

The idea is I just want the directory paths above the file but not the absolute path so only the directories AFTER the initial given path.

I know its a little confusing but I'm sure someone can make sense of it. Right now all I have is a recursive function that prints out file names and their absolute paths.

Any assistance on this?

Comment: What do you meant by *partial file paths*? Here in your post it is root relative `/home/user/test`

Comment: If you have absolute paths, simply chop off their initial part equal to your directory, e.g. `/home/user/test/quick/brown/fox.txt` becomes  `quick/brown/fox.txt` after chopping off the initial `/home/user/test/` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would have been nice if you had tried something and asked questions about that...

However...

```
public class TestFileSearch {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFileSearch();
    }

    public TestFileSearch() {
        File parentPath = new File("C:/Users/shane/Documents");
        List<String> files = list(parentPath);

        for (String file : files) {
            System.out.println(file);
        }
    }

    protected List<String> list(File parent) {
        return listFiles(parent, parent);
    }

    protected List<String> listFiles(File parent, File folder) {
        List<String> lstFiles = new ArrayList<String>(25);
        if (folder.isDirectory()) {

            File[] files = folder.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        lstFiles.addAll(listFiles(parent, file));
                    } else {
                        String path = file.getPath();
                        String offset = parent.getPath();

                        path = path.substring(offset.length());
                        lstFiles.add(path);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return lstFiles;
    }
}
```

You could simply do a normal folder recursion, returning a list of files and THEN strip of the prefix, but that's up to you

Answer (score 1):

What about using the absolute path you currently have but removing the prefix from it using [String.replace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

You said you had the full, absolute path, say in *full* 
then just do

```
String relative = full.replace(prefix, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the input "/home/user/text", all absolute paths to files will start with /home/user/text/. If you're already able to print a list of all files under text/, then all you need to do is take the suitable substring.

The following function should visit all files under pathToDir. In the printFileName function, you can remove the /home/user/text part and print the file names

```
public static void gotoAllFiles(File pathToDir) {
    if (pathToDir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] subdirs = pathToDir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<subdirs.length; i++) {
            gotoAllFiles(new File(pathToDir, subdirs[i]));
        }
    } else {
        printFileName(pathToDir);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, is there an easy way to separate them without having to specify the count of the string? because the substring function takes an int but getting the length of a string returns a long and casting it causes issues.

Comment: What do you mean by 'count' of a string?
The length of a string is almost never going to be outside the range of int. You can safely use (int)longLength.

Answer (score 0):

For each file found, print the `file.getAbsolutePath().substring(rootPath.length());`